# How do I sum a sequence of numbers in Linux bash script?

Tags: bash, numbers, integer, addition

I am trying to sum a sequence of numbers. The code that I have at the moment is

```
seq 0 2 100
```

I want to sum every even number. I am aware of the + operator used for addition. I am a newbie. I do hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: seq 0 2 100 is the code I am trying to use. Is a loop needed? Or something simpler? I Have not learned about loops in Bash. Just a little on loops in Python

Comment: `printf '%s\n' {0..100..2} | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'` or else `seq 0 2 100 | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'`

Comment: `let a=$a+1`, among other possibilities (`a=(($a+1))` should be working as well).

Comment: Did you try other command I gave: `seq 0 2 100 | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'`

Comment: I am getting bash:  printf: '\':   invalid format character for your first example anubhave. But the second exaple worked fine. That's great! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sum every *even* number in a sequence?

```
seq 100 | awk '$1 % 2 == 0 { sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Of course, your `seq` already only prints out even numbers, so

```
seq 0 2 100 | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

or if you have [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/),

```
seq 0 2 100 | datamash sum 1
```

Comment: I am getting datamash: command not found. Why is that? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if that is of relevance.

Comment: @StewartBovis Because you don't have it installed? `apt install datamash`, if an Ubuntu version that old has it available at all.

Comment: Why use `awk` (spawning a new process) instead of bash builtins? (That's a genuine question, more than a criticism).

Comment: @Matthieu If you go that way you don't even need `seq`. Probably worth an answer of its own.

Comment: Pure shell *might* be an issue though with a lot of numbers. It isn't known for speed.